# SQL 重複するレコードを抽出したい

Tags: sql

お世話になっております。
いろいろと調べたのですが、なかなか期待通りの結果が出ないので質問させて頂きます。
　
**tableA**

```
ID　　　DATE　　DAI col1 cal2
22  19970901    0   2   l7  　　　
22  19970901    0   3   r7  　　　　
22  19970912    0   0   NULL    
22  19970912    0   1   R7  　　　
22  19970912    0   2   R76 　　　
22  19970912    0   3   l7　　　　　
22  19971205    0   0   NULL    
22  19971205    0   1   l7  　　　
22  19971205    0   2   l4  　　　
22  19971216    0   0   NULL    
22  19971216    0   1   l7  　　　
22  19971216    0   2   r32 　　　
22  19980127    0   0   NULL    
22  19980127    0   1   R1  　　　
22  19980127    0   2   R3  　　　
22  19980127    1   0   NULL    
22  19980127    1   1   R1  　　
22  19980206    0   0   NULL    
22  19980206    0   1   R2　　　　
22  19980206    0   2   R3　　　　
22  19980206    0   3   R2　　　　　
22  19980217    0   0   NULL　　　　
22  19980217    0   1   R2　　　
22  19980217    0   2   R3　　　
22  19980407    0   0   NULL    
22  19980407    0   1   L67　　　　
22  19980407    0   2   R765    
22  19980428    0   0   NULL    
22  19980428    0   1   L67　　　　
22  19980428    0   2   r7　　　　　
22  19980428    0   3   R7　　　　　
22  19980428    0   4   L2345   
22  19980428    1   0   NULL
```

`cal2`が`null`で、`DAI`が`1`か`0`で、同じ日付のレコード期待値としては

```
22  19980127    0   0   NULL    
22  19980127    1   0   NULL
22  19980428    0   0   NULL
22  19980428    1   0   NULL
```

この４件が抽出できるようにしたいです。
ご教授の程よろしくお願いします。

回答頂いた方すみません。レコードと抽出条件が説明不足でした。

再度書き直したので検討よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

副問い合わせに`HAVING`句を使えばいいのでは。

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA
 WHERE DATE IN
(
    SELECT DATE
      FROM tableA
     GROUP BY DATE
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

上記のSQLについて解説すると、まず`WHERE DATE IN (...)`と副問い合わせを用いることで「レコードの表示」の前に重複する`DATE`をあらかじめ検索することを考えます。

次に「重複する`DATE`の検索」ですが、これには`GROUP BY`と`HAVING`を併用します。`HAVING`句の条件はグループ化の後に評価されるため、`COUNT(*)`は`GROUP BY DATE`の各グループのレコード数を表します。ですので上記の副問い合わせで「重複する`DATE`」を`SELECT`することが可能です。

## 追記

`tableA`に事前に条件を追加したいということですので、payanecoさんの方法で問題ないと思いますが上のSQLを共通表式に対して使用する方法を記載しておきます。

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *
      FROM tableA
     WHERE DAI IN ('0', '1')
       AND cal2 IS NULL
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte
 WHERE DATE IN
(
    SELECT DATE
      FROM cte
     GROUP BY DATE
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

この方式は`cte`の条件が複雑である場合にコードが簡潔になります。今回は2個なので二か所に記述したほうが短くなりますが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。私のレコードと抽出条件が説明不足でした。教えていただいたSQLだと重複する日付で全部出てきてしまうので他の方法をご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 難解にならないよう、あえてwith句を使わずに回答をあげましたが、ご提示頂いた別解の方がDRY原則に合致していて保守しやすいSQLだと思います。

Answer (score 3):

pgrhoさんのSQLをベースにして、WHERE句に抽出条件を追記すれば対応できると思います。
副問い合わせで`19980127`と`19980428`を取得して、外側の主問い合わせでも同様に抽出条件を指定します。

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA
 WHERE DATE IN
(
    SELECT DATE
      FROM tableA
     WHERE cal2 is null
       AND DAI in (0, 1)
     GROUP BY DATE
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
   AND cal2 is null
   AND DAI in (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

window関数の使えるRDBMS(PostgreSQLなど)なら、

```
SELECT
  id, date, dai, col1, cal2
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS dup_count
  FROM
    table1 T1
  WHERE
    cal2 IS NULL
  AND
    dai IN (0, 1)
) AS T1
WHERE
  dup_count >= 2
;
```

とすることで、サブクエリを記述せずに済みます
計算途中の状態をSELECTで確認できるので、ロジックを簡潔に保ちやすいです